# Issues installing Android Development Tools on Eclipse 3.7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Hi I having trouble adding ADT to Eclipse 3.7 I've added the site to the software manager. I tick "Developer Tools" then click next. I get the following error message

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160468326 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160468326)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.4.2.v20110208 (com.ibm.icu 4.4.2.v20110208)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.0.1.v20090822 (com.ibm.icu 4.0.1.v20090822)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.0.1.v20090415 (com.ibm.icu 4.0.1.v20090415)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160468326 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160468326)
    To: com.ibm.icu [4.4.2.v20110208]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EMF Model Utilities 2.0.200.v200905140200 (org.eclipse.jem.util 2.0.200.v200905140200)
    To: bundle com.ibm.icu [3.8.1.1,4.1.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EMF Model Utilities 2.0.201.v201001252130 (org.eclipse.jem.util 2.0.201.v201001252130)
    To: bundle com.ibm.icu [3.8.1.1,4.1.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Common Frameworks 1.1.300.v200904160730 (org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks 1.1.300.v200904160730)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.jem.util [2.0.100,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.1.101.v200908261807 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.1.101.v200908261807)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.validation [1.2.0,1.3.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.1.102.v200910200227 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.1.102.v200910200227)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.validation [1.2.0,1.3.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Validation Framework 1.2.102.v200905201610 (org.eclipse.wst.validation 1.2.102.v200905201610)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks [1.1.200,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Validation Framework 1.2.104.v200911120201 (org.eclipse.wst.validation 1.2.104.v200911120201)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks [1.1.200,2.0.0)
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm running: Eclipse 3.7 64-bit
             Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit

Comment: 64 I believe here is my output from 'java -version'

Comment: java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: I figured it out. Somehow I was dling for Galieo. I changed it to indigo, and it worked fine

Comment: Awesome, be careful of mixing 64bit jdk with Android dev, I've found that it is just easier to go 32 bit for Android.

Comment: Glad you figured this out! You should post your answer as an, um, answer, to make it easier for others to find and to get this post off the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 5):

open eclipse by typing

```
sudo -E eclipse
```

in the terminal , the -E option means preserve the environment , so that it will use the current user's configurations of eclipse .

And ofter opening , install ADT(Android Development Toolkit) following the normal steps .

Answer (score 2):

open eclipse with root rights -> sudo